# Azure Function binding error for signalR (negotiate function) (500 error code)

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I'm creating a live chat using Azure functions and signalR. It works perfectly fine locally, but the deployed "negotiate" function does not work.

negotiate function (index.js)

```
module.exports = function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    context.res = { body: connectionInfo };
    context.done();
}
```

config file (function.json)

```
{
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req"
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
      },
      {
        "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
        "name": "connectionInfo",
        "hubName": "chat",
        "direction": "in",
        "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString"
      }
    ]
  }
```

AzureSignalRConnectionString is set in function app properties.
I also tried using "connectionString" instead of "connectionStringSetting" and using the connection string instead of "AzureSignalRConnectionString" reference, and all 4 possible combinations we have here.

If I run the function in Azure portal, I get this error:

> [Error] Executed 'Functions.negotiate' (Failed, Id=0ac24b1f-1ab0-40f5-9680-34db547e1cc9)
>   Unable to resolve the value for property 'SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (got an answer on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/).
I should have added the AzureSignalRConnectionString in FunctionApp/Configuration/Application settings instead of FunctionApp/Configuration/Application settings/Connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write "connectionStringSetting" as the attribute name in your code ? If so, could you please have a try to change it to "ConnectionStringSetting". You may refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service#configuration) or the screenshot I post below:

[image]

Comment: I tried already, but no success, same error. thanks for answer anyway

Comment: Hi @johnykes , could you please share some more code for how did you get the connection string from app setting in your function app ?

Comment: Sure. In my function -> configuration/application settings, I added "AzureSignalRConnectionString" connection string with value "Endpoint=https://myappsignalr.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=myaccesskey;Version=1.0;" (but with the real values, obviously). Should I do something extra? I can give you reader access if you want to check.

Comment: @johnykes It seems the configuration is all right. For this issue, I think you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The support team can see the background data of your function and help you on it.

Comment: yeah, I had some problems with CDN too few days ago. Maybe my projects are buggy. I'll try the support.